# Vuetify 2.2.6 - Disable toggling in VListGroup

Tags: vue.js, toggle, vuetify.js

I want to allow users to select items in VListGroup but not toggling (i.e. cannot have no selection). How is this possible?

Comment: Why is the negative vote?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the `mandatory` prop of `v-list-item-group`.

Comment: @geeo Here it is [https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/list-item-groups#mandatory](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/list-item-groups#mandatory)